# Select object that has no pointer

Tags: sql, database, postgresql

I have 2 entities named `ContentState` and `HashedFile`.
Each record of `ContentState` has a `HashedFile` linked to it but the relationship is not unique and so there is a many to one relation regarding `ContentState` with `unique="false"` and `not-null="true"` (thus, 2 or more `ContentState` records can point to the same `HashedFile`).
What I'd like to do is to delete a `ContentState` from the database and check for `HashedFile` records that have not `ContentStates` connected to them & delete those as well. What is the PostgreSQL query for this?

THe table columns are as follows:

Table `CONTENT_STATES`:

`id, hashedFileId`, etc.

Table `HASHED_FILES`:

`id`, etc.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `not exists` construction

```
delete HASHED_FILES as hf
where
    not exists (select * from CONTENT_STATES as cs where cs.HashedFileId = h.Id)
```